# BeautifulSoup не обновляет информацию

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Я делаю бота в телеграм парсю сайт погоды с помощью BeautifulSoup.

```
def get_weather():
 response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
 temperatura = soup.find('div', class_='now-weather').text.split()
```

И заметил что когда через время я хочу еще раз посмотреть погоду, то когда вызываеться функция погода не обновляеться а показывает старую температуру. Разве не должно оно при вызове функции по запросу get заходить на сайт и брать уже новую информацию с сайта. Если перезагружу бота то конечно оно тянет инфу, но опять же таки пройдет время и информация остаеться старая.

Answer (score 0):

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
^^^^^^^^
temperatura = soup.find('div', class_='now-weather').text.split()
              ^^^^
```

Ответ с сайта вы получаете в переменной `response`, а данные о температуре получаете из `soup`. Эти две переменные вообще никак между собой не связаны. Вам нужно обновить `soup`, используя `response`. Видимо, вы это делаете где-то в другом месте вашего кода, а тут делать почему-то не стали.

Добавьте строку из вашего комментария между теми двумя строками:

```py
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml') # <-- добавлено
temperatura = soup.find('div', class_='now-weather').text.split()
```

Comment: а как их нужно связать? Я делал по примерах в гугл)

Comment: Ну вот откуда у вас вообще переменная `soup` берётся в коде?

Comment: soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

Comment: Ну вот эту строку и добавьте. Обновил ответ

Comment: def get_weather():
    url = config.site
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0'
    }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

я каждый раз когда нажимаю на кнопку погода в боте, оно вызывает эту функцию